# static_assert referencing enclosing template class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, variadic-templates

In the following code, VS2015 complains at `IsInstantiation<OtherType, T1>::value`, giving this error "invalid template argument for template parameter 'TT', expected a class template".  How would I go about fixing this?  I would like to restrict `OtherType` to cases where T1 is wither `SomeType` or `OtherType`.

```
template <template<typename...> class TT, typename T>
struct IsInstantiation : std::false_type
{
};

template <template<typename...> class TT, typename... Ts>
struct IsInstantiation<TT, TT<Ts...>> : std::true_type
{
};

template <typename T1>
class SomeType{};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
class OtherType
{
    static_assert(IsInstantiation<SomeType, T1>::value ||
        IsInstantiation<OtherType, T1>::value,
        "Event must have SomeType or OtherType as first type");
public:
    explicit OtherType(T1 t1, T2 t2)
        : mT1{ std::move(t1) }
        , mT2{ std::move(t2) }
    {
    }

private:
    T1 mT1;
    T2 mT2;
};
```

Comment: Which one is the "second use"? Can you mark it?

Comment: Barry has improved a lot my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
template <typename, typename>
class OtherType;

template <typename T1, typename T2>
using OtherTypeAlias = OtherType<T1, T2>;

template <typename T1, typename T2>
class OtherType
{
    static_assert(IsInstantiation<SomeType, T1>::value ||
        IsInstantiation<OtherTypeAlias, T1>::value,
        "Event must have SomeType or OtherType as first type");
```

The problem: inside `OtherType`, when you write `OtherType`, it is defaulted to `OtherType<T1, T2>`; so when you pass `OtherType` as argument of `IsIstantiation`, you pass a template type, not a template template.

**-- EDIT --**

I didn't know but is possible to cite directly the dry (without template default parameter) inside `OtherType` (thanks Barry!).

So is a lot simpler

O don't know how to cite directly the class `OtherType` -- as template-template, without the default templates arguments -- inside the body of `OtherType`

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class OtherType
{
    static_assert(IsInstantiation<SomeType, T1>::value ||
        IsInstantiation<::OtherType, T1>::value,
        "Event must have SomeType or OtherType as first type");
```

without alias

Comment: Just write `::OtherType`

Comment: @Barry - the piece that I didn't know (but I had to imagine); thanks.

Comment: This is a bug anyway. Per [temp.local]/1, the injected-class-name should have been treated as referring to the class template in this context.

Comment: @T.C. - Sorry; not sure to understand; do you mean that the code in the question is correct and that is bugged VS2015 (and also my clang++)?

Comment: Yes, @T.C. means that a conforming compiler should accept your original program. (https://godbolt.org/g/CK524M)